# ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I am trying to include one more column in my following query to show the average of two columns within. I am new to SQL and PostgreSQL, but referring the following link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/index.html

```
select ad.col1, ad.col2, md.col3, ad.col4, mcd.col5, 
       AVG(md.col3/mcd.col4) as cb 
from month_date as md 
 JOIN active_date as ad ON ad.col1=md.col1 AND ad.col2=md.col2 
 JOIN mdata1 as mcd ON mcd.col1=md.col1 AND mcd.col2=md.col2;
```

but I am getting the following error while performing the same

```
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested
LINE 1: ...col2,md.col3,ad.col4,mcd.col5, AVG(md.col3/m...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested
SQL state: 42803
Character: 77
```

can anyone guide where am I doing wrong and what I need to correct to make it work.

Output needed:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 |col4 | col5| cb|
```

where `cb` is `average` column of other two columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

Tried to `Group By` but still getting the same error, can anyone correct me what wrong I am also doing in my below query

```
select ad.col1, ad.col2, md.col3, ad.col4, mcd.col5, 
       AVG(md.col3/mcd.col4) as cb 
from month_date as md 
 JOIN active_date as ad ON ad.col1=md.col1 AND ad.col2=md.col2 
 JOIN mdata1 as mcd ON mcd.col1=md.col1 AND mcd.col2=md.col2 GROUP BY ad.col1,ad.col2,md.col3,ad.col4,mcd.col5;
```

Comment: Do you just want to show the division of the two values, or an average of all the values in the column, grouped by the other columns you explicited?

Comment: I created a fiddle with your example, can cannot see why you're getting the error, can you check for the differences? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/be661/1

Comment: I just needed to show the average of divisions of two columns e.g: avg(8/2) also further in another column I needed to show avg(8+2/2), I am new to queries, so might be I made a mistake, could you please correct me what am I suppose to do in that case?

Comment: Thank you Alex, you are right and its the same what I am performing, I am not sure why am I getting that error in `postgreSQL` :(

Comment: Is there any chance you are running this query within another query?

Comment: I am running this query as standalone. Let me quickly create a dummy table and check in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks Alex, it worked, I made a mistake in mapping of correct columns in `aliases` :)

Comment: Excellent! I will make an answer for this, you can accept it if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I created [a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/be661/1) with your example, and you can see that the query as it is works. It is probably an error in a wrapping query, store procedure or function.

Answer (score 2):

To use AVG() or any sort of aggregate functions in SQL, you need to have a GROUP BY for the other columns you're displaying.

Think of it this way, when you SELECT a column, you display rows. When you show an average, you show a single output. You can't put rows and a single output together.

You'll need to try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT col1, col2, AVG(col3)
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Comment: Thank you d_ominic, yes you are right. I have done the same individually in a single query, but how can I integrate the same in my above query that I have mentioned which already have two `inner join`

Comment: Tried like this: `select ad.col1, ad.col2, md.col3, ad.col4, mcd.col5, 
       AVG(md.col3/mcd.col4) as cb 
from month_date as md 
 JOIN active_date as ad ON ad.col1=md.col1 AND ad.col2=md.col2 
 JOIN mdata1 as mcd ON mcd.col1=md.col1 AND mcd.col2=md.col2 GROUP BY ad.col1,ad.col2,md.col3,ad.col4,mcd.col5;` but still the same error, can you please correct me if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Hmm Strange. And with the fiddle alex siri made, your edited query looks ok...Can you show us the table structure and data types you're using?